# Which is correct, "go to swim", "go to swimming", or "go swimming"? What are the differences?

Tags: difference, infinitive-vs-gerund

> I want to ***go to swim***.
>
> I want to ***go swimming***.
>
> I want to ***go to swimming***.

I wonder which one is correct and how to tell the difference between them.

Comment: All three mean the same thing.


  [1]: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55431/which-would-you-use-go-for-a-swim-or-going-swimming

Comment: I don't think any of them will be preferred. *I want to go **for a swim*** where *swim* is a noun. If you want to use *verb*, then *I want to go for swimming* looks better to me.

Comment: @Maulik: Nah. *"I want to go **for** swimming"* is an extremely unlikely construction that in most contexts I would simply dismiss as "ungrammatical", whereas OP's second example (without ***for***) is perfectly natural phrasing.

Answer (score 7):

> I want to go to swim.

Phrasing it this way implies that your primary goal is to swim. For instance, it would be the proper response to the question "Why do you want to go to the lake?"

> I want to go swimming.

Phrasing it this way implies a desire to perform the act of swimming. It is more of a general intention to go swimming anywhere. It is equivalent to saying "I want to go *for a swim*."

> I want to go to swimming.

Phrasing it this way does not make sense.

Answer (score -1):

First one is correct. I want to go to swim. Here to swim is infinitive form of verb . so infinitive form always takes to+ first form of verb
While go to swimming is wrong. Go for swimming iscorrect.  Swimming is acting as a gerund

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. While *I want to go to swim* is grammatically correct, the bare infinitive forms *I want to go swim* or *I want to go swimming* are more idiomatic. There are situations in which each of the pains is preferable.