# Is there a difference between "go {for the walking/for a walk/walking}" ?

Tags: gerunds

> (1) Did you go **for the walking**?
>
> (2) Did you go **for a walk**?
>
> (3) Did you go **walking**?

Is there any difference between three of them? For me it is right. I am talking about the grammatical as well as the meaning difference. I think the three sentences are well. Some people told me that the first sentence isn't correct. 
I understand that it is correct, It follows the grammar rule.

Did+sub+verb+preposition(for)+object of preposition which is noun(walking - gerund of walk(verb)

Comment: Possible duplicates:  [What is the difference between 'want camping' and 'I want to camp'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/79522/what-is-the-difference-between-want-camping-and-i-want-to-camp) and [Which is correct, “go to swim”, “go to swimming”, or “go swimming”? What are the differences?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/23822/which-is-correct-go-to-swim-go-to-swimming-or-go-swimming-what-are-the?rq=1) and [What is the difference between 'go camping' and 'go to camp'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/82491/what-is-the-difference-between-go-camping-and-go-to-camp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three are grammatically correct but (1) has a different meaning to (2) and (3).

Sentence (1) asks whether the walking was the reason that you went.  For example, if a group of friends go for a walk together, the answer to "Did you go for the walking?" might be "No. I went for the conversation."

Sentences (2) and (3) have almost identical meanings.